# What are the major differences between Madden games for the PC, post 2003?

Tags: version-differences, madden-series

The last football game I bought for the PC was Madden 2003. I just bought a new system and am interested in buying a new version of Madden Football to go along with it.

What are the major differences are between each Madden game from 2006 to present?

Comment: You should change your question so it fits the format for this site http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Unfortunately game recommendations are off topic for this site ... you are welcome to ask these questions in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), but the Stack Exchange format doesn't lend itself well to recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a list of differences between each.

2006 -

- New Superstar Mode. This mode allows the user to create (or import from NCAA Football 06 or NFL Street 2) a player. Once this player is created the user plays this player and controls this players career, but doesn't control any of the other front office activities for the team.
- New Field of Vision Cone. This makes the game a little more realistic and potentially a lot harder. The QB now has a cone that shows where the QB is looking. The user can move this cone from side to side. If the user tries to throw a pass to a receiver not in the cone, accuracy can suffer greatly. I say potentially harder because some QBs, Peyton Manning, Brett Favre, Tom Brady etc. can see most of the field while other lower ranked QBs can hardly see anything.
- Precision Passing. This allows the user to "choose" where the pass is going to go relative to the receiver by throwing the ball high, low, in front of, or behind by aiming your thumb stick or directional pad up, down, left, or right.
- Truck Stick! 2005 added the Hit Stick which allowed defensive players to hit harder by moving the right thumb stick toward the person they are hitting. 2006 added the Truck Stick which allows the runner with the ball to move the right thumb stick toward the defender to try and "plow" them down at the risk of a fumble.

2007 -

- Lead Blocker Control. After you choose your running play you can cycle through offensive players and choose one. After you snap the ball you will be able to control that player to setup a block that the computer controlled player might miss. After you make your block you can switch back to the running back and run through the hole you just made.
- Highlight Stick. Added more moves to the Truck Stick from 2006. You can juke left and right, hop step backwards, and of course still lower your head and smash the defender in front of you.
- Juking and Spinning. You can choose how big or small your juke is by using shoulder buttons for a quick cut, or using the analog stick to do a bigger juke. You can also choose to do a quick spin or a big spin by just tapping or holding down the spin button.

2008 -

- Player "Weapons". Certain players can be labelled as a weapon. It can increase their performance and those players can create game-changing plays. For example, players with the "Smart Quarterback" weapon are able to read defensive schemes and audible accordingly. Possession receivers can make tough catches over the middle, Shutdown corners can stay on even the toughest receivers, and Spectacular Catch receivers are able to leap over defenders and make difficult grabs.
- You can change players positions. This allows you to change a receiver to a tight end or an offensive lineman to a defensive lineman to potentially increase a players performance and stats.
- Added features to Superstar mode. You can still import from NCAA, as well as creating one or playing different rookies from the 2007 Draft. Camera angles were tweaked and you now put points into stats yourself instead of them being randomly chosen.

2009, 10, 11, 12 -

- Not released for PC